# Add console to existing MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I'm working with 2 friends in a class project to make a D&D game. so far for the assignments I've been doing character creation stuff and strutting on the command line.

Now we're bringing or part together and I need to output ny dice rolls on a console and a few things on another one that will have to become the main view or tab or whatever it's called when it requires input/attention.

Problem is I never learned MFC yet because I didn't need it. How hard would it be to make a sample MFC console all that I can give to the teammate in charge of the GUI?

Could anyone point me to some instruction on making a console for an MFC app and how to give it output and receive output?

Comment: [::AlocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx) and friends

Comment: Does this just make cout and cin make a console open? How would I have 2 consoles? I need a bit more detail than just a function.

Comment: @Portaljacker: You can't have more than one console window, unless you implement it yourself. Whether `cout` works, try and see. I think it should.

Comment: @Portaljacker: also note, mine was a comment, not an answer. I _understand_ you need more than that. If you knew the API calls for it, you should have mentioned them in the question :)

Comment: I'll try when I get home from work tonight. if it works I suggest you make it into an answer so I can get you some rep.

Comment: Whoops, I assumed that if I saidi made a console app that it meant I used cout and cin.

Comment: @sehe I think you should post your suggestion as an answer. Used AllocConsole with _cprintf() and _cscanf_s()

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't. for both Unix/Linux and Windows, there is a one console/process limit. If you want another console, you have to create another process, that writes and reads the other console, while you send and receive the data.

You can use a NamedPipe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx to send data between processes, and the `CreateProcess()` function lets you create a process with a separate Console window.

Alternatively you can just write a Console-Look-a-Like window in some GUI.